# advantages of JDBC over plsql?

Tags: database, jdbc, plsql

I am revising for a databases exam. A previously asked question asks about the advantages of JDBC over plsql and viceversa?

I have found it easy to find advantages of plsql over Jdbc 
for example:

Better Performance- as with PL/SQL, an entire block of statements can be sent to Oracle at one time. This can drastically reduce network traffic between the database and an application.

Portability-Applications written in PL/SQL can run on any operating system and platform where the Oracle database runs

Productivity- implicit connection handling, intigrated termination test, cleaner parameter parsing.

Tight Security- PL/SQL stored procedures move application code from the client to the server, where you can protect it from tampering, hide the internal details, and restrict who has access.

what are advantages of JDBC over plsql?

Comment: You mean plsql as in PL/SQL? Because so far the question makes no sense to me. Can you elaborate on what are those advantages you talk about?

Comment: Hi I've tried to elaborate on the advantages. Sorry if it wasn't clear before.

Comment: The JDBC is an API that can be used to connect to databases and issue PL/SQL commands. As such, the comparison, the way you are presenting it, still makes no sense to me.

Comment: @edalorzo I think that he's trying to compare a single block of PL/SQL and the version of this code decomposed in jdbc calls (e.g. one query for the cursor data, other for insert / update / delete...)

Comment: I agree however thats what the question is asking for on the past paper exam and thats why i am confused. I would guess that it is perhaps asking the advantages of using jdbc without plsql instead using prepared statements over just plsql.

Comment: there can not be any comparison between JDBC and PLSQL , it always depends on the requirement of application ,both approaches have advantages and disadvantages . for PL SQL you get better performance but round the way other with JDBC you get better debug functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database independence is good reason for using JDBC. Let's say that your web application needs to run for a customer that cannot pay for Oracle, how much work will you need to do to port to a open source database?

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps two other reasons could be that JDBC is object oriented and the returned result is easier to process and manipulate in java?

Answer (score 1):

JDBC is better if you have to do several calculations with your set of data, sometimes you can even do the joins in the client side releasing the server from doing such heavy work.